# Draw a circle smoothly transforming to a line

Tags: flutter, canvas, material-ui, slider, paint

I faced the problem in my Flutter app that I can't draw this kind of a shape for my Slider
[image: slider I need to get]

What I have now is:

```
final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final rect = Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: thumbRadius);
    final rrect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
      Rect.fromPoints(
        Offset(rect.left - 5, rect.top),
        Offset(rect.right + 5, rect.bottom),
      ),
      Radius.circular(thumbRadius + 2),
    );

    canvas.drawRRect(rrect, paint);
```

[image: current slider]

Also, it would be great to change height of all bar, because next code changes only the size after player

```
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderThemeData(
  trackHeight: 2,
  thumbShape: CustomSliderPlayer(),
  ),
  child: Slider(...)
```

Comment: you need a `Path` and two [quadratic bezier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/quadraticBezierTo.html) curves

Comment: @pskink how am I supposed to change position, it feels like it just for 1 concrete place and will not change position after moving a slider

Comment: first call `Path.moveTo` - btw you want the curve like in the first image or circle like in your question title?

Comment: @pskink I definitely want curve like in the first image, I just don't know how to call it

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it looks like you are not familiar with quadratic bezier curves, they are very simple, I would recommend you to start on a Javascript canvas, they are easier to test that way and logic is the same, we move to the starting point then we draw the curve, see sample snippet below

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function dobleQuad(x, y, w, h) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x - w, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y - h, x + w, y);
  ctx.moveTo(x - w, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, x + w, y);
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawSlider(x, y) {
  ctx.moveTo(0, y - 2);
  ctx.fillRect(0, y - 2, canvas.width, 4);
  dobleQuad(x, y, 20, 22)
}

drawSlider(50, 50)

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  drawSlider( evt.clientX - rect.left, 50 )
})
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Just keep in mind that in JS it's `quadraticCurveTo` but in flutter `quadraticBezierTo`

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/quadraticCurveTo

```txt
void ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cpx, cpy, x, y);

cpx, cpy 
The coordinates of the control point.

x, y
The coordinates of the end point.
```

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/quadraticBezierTo.html

```txt
void quadraticBezierTo(
  double x1,  double y1,
  double x2,  double y2
)

Adds a quadratic bezier segment that curves from the current point
to the given point (x2,y2), using the control point (x1,y1).
```

Comment: it's kinda fine, isn't exactly what I've was looking for, but made it with flutter and it works almost fine.
Now, I'm drawing slider just with multiplying it's position (0.0 to 1.0) by 325, isn't the best way I guess `drawSlider(25 + sliderPosition * 325, 25);`